# removing c comments from a file

Tags: c, file-io, comments

I know this type of question has been answered before, but I have my own solution and I would like to solve the bug in it. I'm not worried about in quote comments, I know this code wont handle them. The problem is that the initial `/` starting off the `/* … */` comment gets printed to the file when it should not be.

```
int cleanFile( char *fileName ){

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
int inComment = 0;
char current, next;

//will return exit exicution if the file does not exist
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("%s", "File was not found.\nFile is expected to be in src directory.");
    return 0;
}
//creat a new file for the clean input
FILE *cf;
cf = fopen( "cleaninput.txt", "w" );

current = fgetc(fp);

while(current != EOF){

    if( inComment == 0 ){

        if(current == '/')
        {
            next = fgetc(fp);

                //look ahead and see if this is the start of a comment
                if(next == '*')
                {

                    inComment = 1;
                    current = next;   //CODE JUMPS FROM HERE 

                }else{

                    fputc(current, cf);
                    current = next;

                }
        }else{
            fputc(current, cf);
            current = fgetc(fp); // AND LANDS HERE
        }

    //if an exit sequence is found set in comment to false
    }else{
        if(current == '*')
        {
            next = fgetc(fp);
            if(next == '/')
            {
                inComment = 0;
                current = next;
            }
        }else{
            current = fgetc(fp);
        }
    }
}//end while

fclose(fp);
fclose(cf);

return 1;
}
```

Comment: I'd use a scripting language

Comment: @P0W: A higher abstraction language like Python, yes, but not a scripting language.

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  Therefore, `current` must be an `int`.  Otherwise, you cannot reliably detect EOF, though if your plain `char` type is signed, you will usually get away with it.

Comment: I think your problem is not that the leading `/` is printed; it is more likely the trailing `/` that is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that the leading `/` is printed but that the trailing `/` is printed.  You can fix this by setting `current` to the next input character instead of to `next` when `next` is `/`.

With some other (minimal) fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int cleanFile(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    int inComment = 0;
    int current, next;

    /* will return exit execution if the file does not exist */
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", "File was not found.\nFile is expected to be in src directory.");
        return 0;
    }
    /* create a new file for the clean input */
    FILE *cf = fopen("cleaninput.txt", "w");

    current = fgetc(fp);

    while (current != EOF)
    {
        if (inComment == 0)
        {
            if (current == '/')
            {
                next = fgetc(fp);
                if (next == EOF)
                {
                    fputc(current, cf);
                    break;
                }

                /* look ahead and see if this is the start of a comment */
                if (next == '*')
                {
                    inComment = 1;
                    current = fgetc(fp);
                }
                else
                {
                    fputc(current, cf);
                    current = next;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fputc(current, cf);
                current = fgetc(fp);
            }
        }
        else if (current == '*')
        {
            next = fgetc(fp);
            if (next == '/')
            {
                inComment = 0;
                current = fgetc(fp);
            }
            else
            {
                current = next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current = fgetc(fp);
        }
    }/* end while */

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(cf);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *filename = "cc23.c";
    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    if (cleanFile(filename))
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("Oops!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

One minor issue is that this doesn't replace a comment with a blank, which could change the meaning (or validity) of a program.

I would use a function to peek at the next character if it were my own code:

```
int fpeekc(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = getc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, fp);
    return c;
}
```

It would simplify the lookahead logic.  I'd also redesign the function to work on an already open file stream and to write to a specified file stream — it make the code more general.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * This is adequate for routine comments.
 * It wouldn't spot /\
 * * as the start of a comment, or *\
 * / as the end of a comment (where the " * " line prefix should be ignored).
 */

static int fpeekc(FILE *fp)
{
    int c = getc(fp);
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetc(c, fp);
    return c;
}

static void cleanFile(FILE *fin, FILE *fout)
{
    int inComment = 0;
    int current, next;

    while ((current = getc(fin)) != EOF)
    {
        if (inComment == 0)
        {
            if (current == '/' && fpeekc(fin) == '*')
            {
                next = getc(fin);
                assert(next == '*');
                inComment = 1;
            }
            else
                putc(current, fout);
        }
        else if (current == '*' && fpeekc(fin) == '/')
        {
            inComment = 0;
            next = fgetc(fin);
            assert(next == '/');
        }
        /* else do not echo comment characters */
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *filename = "cc29.c";
    if (argc == 2)
        filename = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s for reading\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    cleanFile(fp, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Backslash-newline combinations complicate comment handling — fortunately, you probably don't need to worry about them unless you're writing a C preprocessor.  You do have to worry about character strings and multi-character literals such as `'/*'` — the latter are not portable but are nonetheless valid and do not start a comment.  And C++ raw strings are another level of complexity again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the comment doesn't span multiple lines, wouldn't it be easier if you ignore the entire line when the first character starts with the forward slash?

I think the problem might be in your second IF-statement, check your conditional expression. If the character read is not an asterisks, your program writes to the file immediately.

If you have the following line in your source code.

```
// Something here
```

Your program reads the first character, in this case the forward slash, then it reads the second character which is also the forward slash, not an asterisks. As a result, the ELSE-statement executes instead causing your program to write to the output file rather than ignoring the entire line.

Comment: Comments do span multiple lines.  Comments can occur multiple times on a single line: `extern int somefunc(int /*arg1*/, char */*arg2*/);` for example.  If you get lackadaisical about handling comments, other people's code will bite you.  People do the weirdest and most irritating things in their code — and a comment stripper can't afford to be wrong.